# Нужна помощь с регулярным выражением C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Я пишу бота с возможностью банить пользователей на определённый срок. Я ввожу срок бана в формате 0г0мес0д0ч0мин0с. Писать нулевые значения необязательно, например:
не 0г0мес7д12ч0мин0с, а просто 7д12ч. Мне кажется, что эффективнее всего реализовать это при помощи регулярных выражений. Программа получает срок в виде строки, а возвращает массив групп внутри матча.
Вот мой код:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(??????);
        MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(time);

        for (int i = 4 - 1; i < match[0].Groups.Count; i += 4)
        {

            switch (match[0].Groups[i].Value)
            {

                case "г":
                    unban_date = unban_date.AddYears(Convert.ToInt32(match[0].Groups[i - 1].Value));
                    break;
                case "мес":
                    unban_date = unban_date.AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(match[0].Groups[i - 1].Value));
                    break;
                case "д":
                    unban_date = unban_date.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(match[0].Groups[i - 1].Value));
                    break;
                case "ч":
                    unban_date = unban_date.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(match[0].Groups[i - 1].Value));
                    break;
                case "мин":
                    unban_date = unban_date.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(match[0].Groups[i - 1].Value));
                    break;
                case "с":
                    unban_date = unban_date.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(match[0].Groups[i - 1].Value) / 10000);
                    break;
            }
        }

        var diffOfDates = unban_date - date_now;

        ban_period += diffOfDates.Days == 0 ? "" : diffOfDates.Days.ToString() + " дней ";
        ban_period += diffOfDates.Hours == 0 ? "" : diffOfDates.Hours.ToString() + " часов ";
        ban_period += diffOfDates.Minutes == 0 ? "" : diffOfDates.Minutes.ToString() + " минут ";
        ban_period += diffOfDates.Seconds == 0 ? "" : diffOfDates.Seconds.ToString() + " секунд ";
```

Мне нужна помощь в написании регулярного выражения, с помощью которого я смогу получать группы в формате:

1мес

1

мес

и так далее. Я перечитал всевозможные статьи о регулярных выражениях, но так и не смог его написать.

Comment: Сам себе придумал проблему: есть задача, придумал решение, для которого нужно ещё одно решение. Может, стоит изменить первоначальное решение? Можно изменить формат команды бана так, чтобы регулярные выражения не понадобились, чтобы команда была удобна для формирования человеком и проста для раскодирования программой.

Comment: Для начала, бан на года попросту не имеет смысла, ибо это равноценно вечной блокировке, а значит оперировать таким набором данных вам попросту бессмысленно, достаточно 3, а именно дни, часы, минуты, секунды как по мне тоже бесполезны, за 30 условных секунд человек не успокоится. Далее, вам стоит научиться использовать стандартные решения языка, а именно `DateTime` (если нужны года) и `TimeSpan` (если достаточно 3 значений, перечисленных ранее), у них есть метод `Parse()`, который преобразует строку правильного формата в объект, а также есть `ParseExact` если формат нестандартный.

Comment: Кстати вместо `Convert.ToInt32` советую опробовать `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никакого смысла в `г` и `м`, потому что есть соответственно `365д` и `30д` для этого. Секунды можно выбросить, ну потому что смысла в них тоже нет.

Вот и остаются `д`, `ч` и `мин`, хотя буква `м` уже освободилась.

Далее, есть ли смысл в бане, скажем в `1д1ч`? Я как банивший нарушителей на потоке (более 5 банов в минуту), скажу, что смысла нет. Бан идёт либо на часы, либо на дни. Но если сил нет как хочется `1д1ч`, то `25ч` к вашим услугам.

Итого, всю эту историю можно свести к регулярке `(\d+)(д|ч|м)`, где первая группа - число, а вторая - множитель. Кстати, познакомтесь с сайтом [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), очень помогает писать и проверять регулярки.

А модератору будет очень просто задать срок блокировки.